# Iterators comparisions in STL

Tags: c++, stl

Below is text from Scott Meyers Effective STL regarding iterators Item 26.

```
typedef deque<int> IntDeque; //STL container and
typedef lntDeque::iterator Iter; // iterator types are easier
typedef lntDeque::const_iterator Constlter; // to work with if you
// use some typedefs

Iter i;
Constlter ci;
… //make i and ci point into
// the same container
if (i == ci ) ... //compare an iterator
                  // and a const_iterator
```

All we're doing here is comparing two iterators into a container, the kind of comparison that's the bread and butter of the STL. The only twist is that one object is of type iterator and one is of type const_iterator. This should be no problem. The iterator should be implicitly convened into a const_iterator. and the comparison should be performed between two const_iterators.

With well-designed STL implementations, this is precisely what happens, but with other implementations, the code will not compile. The reason is that such implementations declare operator== for const_iterators as a member function instead of as a non-member function, but the cause of the problem is likely to be of less interest to you than the workaround, which is to swap the order of the iterators, like this:

```
if (ci == i)... // workaround for when the
                // comparison above won't compile
```

My question on above

1. Why author mean only const_iterator member function is called, it is also possible iterator member function is called for operator == ?

Comment: The book is 15+ years old and talks about early C++98 implementations. In the original standard the implicit conversion from iterator to const_iterator might not have been explicitly spelled out, and so implementations differed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the comparison operators compare `iterator` with `iterator` and `const_iterator` with `const_iterator`. If the operators are non-member functions the compiler will find the conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator` and call the `const_iterator` comparison function. If the comparison operator is a member function it will be called on the lhs which, in the example, is an `iterator` and there is no way to convert a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`. What the workaround does is to put the `const_iterator` as lhs and since `iterator` can be converted to `const_iterator` the comparison compiles.